# Low disk space truncate

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

When you have a low disk situation with a log file taking up some GB and you have no disk space left  what is the best course of action without losing any of logs?

Things I tried was to mv the log file and compress, but this will show up as deleted in lsof which might be a problem in the future.

Possibly gzip the log file and kill -1 the process. But is this something that you do a production server for services like httpd and mysql?

Thanks.
Ob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If storage is 100% full, the compression won't work as there is no space for a temporary file.

Copy logs to other storage.  `scp -r /var/log/ otherhost:`

Review and delete old log files.  `find /var/log -mtime +7`

Expand file system if necessary.

Compress some large files. Reload services to open a new log file. `gzip /var/log/httpd/access_log ; systemctl reload httpd.service`

Implement logrotate or equivalent script to manage these automatically. The usual pattern is to move the current file to a new name, and reopen a new log file.

Consider implementing a remote log server and shipping logs off the host instead.

---

Whether sending a signal to a service or otherwise reloading it is acceptable is up to you.  Of course, you can try it on a test system if this makes you nervous.

If you don't tell the service to open a new file there is another option:  truncate in place.  `cp /dev/null  file.log`   or logrotate option `copytruncate`.   However, beware the warning about this not being atomic from the lograte man page:

> Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file
>   and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost.

Answer (score 1):

for apache use USR1 signal:

## killall -USR1 httpd

and for mysql flush logs command:

## mysqladmin flush-logs

but probably you would be better by using logrotate to rotate logs and usually it comes with configs for apache/mysql, which basically does it for you and gzips logs. It is common practice on production servers.

Comment: This answer needs a lot more detail. A reader who doesn't know how logrotate works isn't going to know after reading this answer either.